# Fill value by value a char *

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, char

I'm trying to fill a `char *info` inside a `struct nodo;`

This is struct :

```
struct nodo {
char *info;
struct nodo *prec;
struct nodo *succ;
};
typedef struct nodo nodo;
```

And this is whole function :

```
nodo *q,*t = NULL,*head = NULL;
int i, nodi=0 ;
char *c = a, *k = a;

while ( *c != '\0') {
    if (*c == ' ')
        nodi++;
    c++;
}

for (i = 0; nodi != 0; i++) {
    if (i == 0){
        head = CreateFirstNodo();
        t = head;}
    if (i == 1)
        q = CreateSecondNodo(head);
    else
        q = CreateNNodo(head);
    nodi--;

}


char *k = a;
int i = 0;
while ( *k != '\0' )
{        
    if (*k == ' ' )
    {
        head = head->succ; 
        i = 0;
    }
    head->info[i] = *k; // ERROR EXC BAD ACCESS 
    i++;
    k++;
}
return t;
}
```

`k` is a `char*` and should scroll the `char[]` to which is assigned and should copy any of his values to the proper place in `head->info[i]` which is `char *info` in `struct`

if `k` hits a space, the nodo goes to the next nodo and the 'i' become 0 again since `i` need a word filled in each nodo.

BUT this code shows error EXC BAD ACCESS in the marked line.

Here are the 3 CreateNodo functions:

```
nodo *CreateFirstNodo() {
nodo *q;

q = malloc(sizeof(nodo));
q->prec = NULL;
q->succ = NULL;

return q;
}

nodo *CreateSecondNodo(nodo *head) {
nodo *q;

q = malloc(sizeof(nodo));
q->succ = NULL;
q->prec = head;
head->succ = q;

return q;
}


nodo *CreateNNodo(nodo *head) {

nodo *q;

while (head->succ != NULL) {
    head = head ->succ;
}

q = malloc(sizeof(nodo));
q->succ = NULL;
q->prec = head;
head->succ = q;

return q;
```

EDIT: sorry for lacking code.

Comment: Where are the definitions?

Comment: Show us `struct head` please, although I guess `head->info` is not of type `char **` or  defined as `char * info[N]`.

Comment: There is quite-literally more code *missing* to accurately help with this question than there is *provided*. Please produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) containing all related pieces for *us* to reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: Show the `struct`, how you declare `info`?

Comment: I guess you are Italian, and that `struct nodo` defines a node in some linked tree or chain structure, but searching throws up many different such `struct nodo`s: you really_**must**_ tell us what your definition is. As @WhozCraig said, we need a [proper code example (MVCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then we can help you.

Comment: For an error to occur there, `head` is `null` or a bad pointer, `info` is a bad pointer, `info[i]` had read passed the end of its array (which is my guess), or `k` is a bad pointer or has read passed the end of its array/string.

Comment: I guess you want to produce chain of nodo's, each containing one ‘word’ from `*k`, where ‘word’ is defined as the characters between delimited by the start of the string, any internal space and the terminating `'\0'`. You do not tell us if the chain of `nodo`s has been set up beforehand, with some assumption on the limit, or if you are meant to allocate them on demand. Similarly, you do not say if the `info`s in the `nodo`s have been allocated in advance, or should be allocated on demand and expanded as needed. It looks as though you assume both allocations just happen by magic as needed!

Comment: I also wonder if you really want to put the delimiting space in `info`, which is what you are doing. If not you need to advance `k`, but then you need to repeat the loop. What do you want to do with multiple spaces? Empty words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get EXC BAD ACCESS is because you never actually allocate memory for `info`. In your `struct nodo` you have `info` defined to be a pointer to a character, but you never have any memory allocated for it.

Depending on how big your input could be you could either do `char info[256]` (or whatever size you want) or you could `calloc` the amount of space you want in `Createxxxx` functions.

Additionally, you really only need one `Create` function. I would do something like this:

```
nodo *CreateNodo(nodo *head)
{
    nodo *q;

    q = calloc(1, sizeof(nodo));
    if (q) {
        //assume info should be 256 chars
        q->info = calloc(256, sizeof(char));
        if (!q->info) {
            free(q);
            return NULL;
        }
        q->succ = NULL;
        q->prec = NULL;

        if (head) {
            while (head->succ != NULL) {
                head = head->succ;
            }
            q->prec = head;
            head->succ = q;
        }

    return (q);
}
```

That way you only have 1 function to debug/fix.

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to dereference an uninitialized pointer, probably (an initialization is not shown).

When you access `info[i]` what it does is add `info + i` and use that as an address to find a `char`. If `info` has an invalid value (such as NULL), then you get the error you see.

You probably need to initialize `info` with something like `info = malloc(size_i_want)`, but it's hard to see what you're trying to achieve here.